# Making the whole filesystem accessible over WebDAV

Tags: apache2, webdav

I have a server which runs Ubuntu 13.04 and I want to access it using WebDAV (as SSHFS is too slow, and security isn’t that important in my case). I tried setting it up with Apache, but it didn’t work because Apache user, `www-data`, doesn’t have root privileges needed for accessing everything. And Apache refused to run as `root` either.

What can I do to solve this? I would much prefer not complicating matters by switching to NFS or Samba through a VPN. It’s just a small cheap server after all.

Comment: Wait a minute. You want to provide read-access to your *complete* filesystem (`/`) and you don't care about security? I think you should care about security if this box is connected to the danger of the world wide web. :)

Comment: Why not ssh? it's secure and fast and you gain access to the **whole** computer...

Comment: @gertvdijk: worse, readwrite access :) However, with a mere login and pass anybody can do anything to it anyway, so I don’t see how WebDAV with a password is worse than SSH.

Comment: @Alvar: WebDAV has native support on Windows and Android. (Also SSHFS is slow and I wasn’t so far able to find how to make it fast enough.)

Comment: webdav isn't encrypted as SSH is. So any router in the way can access the data being sent, that's one of the reasons SSH is more secure.

Comment: If you're running sshfs you can use public key rather than password.

Comment: @Alvar: WebDAV over HTTPS is encrypted, and the level of encryption SSL provides is quite enough for me.

Comment: @Marc: Currently I’m using ssh with a password anyway, so WebDAV wouldn’t worsen the level of security. And sshfs *is not an option*, it’s not fast enough and it isn’t supported on a random Windows computer.

Comment: Just because you are now, doesn't mean you have to tomorrow.

Comment: @Alvar: there’s no ssh on a random Windows computer. Period. What I’m trying to achieve is to be able to walk to any computer, connect to my server and easily configure it / grab a file from it / put a file on it / look at logs / … I don’t see why I should use ten separate tools for every one of my tasks when I can use one to rule them all.

Comment: OK with me if *you* do it, but I wouldn't expose my entire system to the known universe with only a password for security, then use that password on random computers with no idea of their trustworthiness. Bad mojo.

Comment: @Marc: luckily there’s a great solution for this and similar password-related problems: [time-based authentication](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/). Still *much* more convenient to use on a random computer than public keys.

Comment: Hmmm . . . doesn't do anything I need, but an interesting approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you can tell by the comments, your use case is far from conventional or recommended. You are trying to mount and modify an entire filesystem by using an apache process running *inside* a permissions and security model on that filesystem.  This problem will not go away, because Apache is of course designed to prevent remote persons from controlling the whole damn filesystem (including the parts "underneath" Apache or root).  So you need to:

1. rethink your problem as one that fits inside the Apache model, or
2. find some system-level webdav support (unlikely), or
3. forget about webdav (most likely).

Probably a combination of 1 and 3.  You cannot legitimately want to be able to overwrite, say, libc remotely.  This is why we are looking at you strangely.  What are you trying to affect?  If you are trying to use this to roll out system configuration changes, find an appropriate tool (chef, puppet, etc.).  If you are using this as deployment mechanism (say for websites or applications), try a build tool like gradle.

If you are *that* worried about speed, you shouldn't be remotely mounting a filesystem anyway.  For example, when you would prefer to bundle a series of edits and deliver them **compressed** in a semantic group... then you're talking about **git** (version control).  No persistent connection, nothing more than SSL needed, compressed storage, compressed communication, rollback capability, etc.  But even in that case you shouldn't be messing w/ binaries on the running system.

Comment: I’m not *that* worried about speed, it’s just that it took **more than one minute** to load the *contents* of an SSHFS-shared folder on my laptop. Any directory navigation is literally impossible.

Comment: And I don’t want to overwrite libc remotely :) A lot of config files are unaccessible by Apache. Log files, too. I know that there’s a better—more convential—way for solving any of my problems, but far too often I find myself wishing for easy complete r/w access when I stumble upon a problem *I hadn’t thought of*.